# How Can I Connect To A Local WebSocket Server with Uno Platform WebAssembly

Tags: uno-platform

The following code works with UWP but not WASM. I do have the Uno.Wasm.WebSockets package installed on the WASM head.

```
_webSocketConnectionCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
using (_webSocket = new ClientWebSocket())
{
    try
    {
        await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(address), _webSocketConnectionCTS.Token);
        await Receive(_webSocket, _webSocketConnectionCTS.Token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to WebSocket server: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown on the connect: "Value cannot be null" but neither parameter is null.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientWebSocket` class is not available in current builds of Uno, as the underlying class is not providing an implementation for it. You can use the [`Uno.Wasm.WebSockets`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Wasm.WebSockets) package instead, which uses the same APIs as `ClientWebSocket`.

Here's an example from [the documentation](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno.wasm.websockets):

```cs
var ws = new Uno.Wasm.WebSockets.WasmWebSocket();

// Connect to a simple echo WebSocket server
await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://echo.websocket.org"), CancellationToken.None);

Console.WriteLine("Program: Connected!");

// Send some data
var data = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello websocket !"));
await ws.SendAsync(data, System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, CancellationToken.None);

Console.WriteLine("Program: Sent!");

// Read the echo back
var buffer = new byte[1024];
var received = await ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

var receivedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received.Count);
Console.WriteLine($"Received {received.Count} bytes: {receivedString}");
```

Comment: The nuget package was installed but the namespace Uno.Wasm.WebSockets is not available. [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/QJWvm95/Annotation-2020-09-01-125037.jpg)

Comment: The class is available here (https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.WebSockets/blob/9829c95bea0297149caabb0aaa150e5bbd6e6e66/src/Uno.Wasm.WebSockets/WasmWebSocket.cs#L12), and is part of the nuget package. if you're not seeing it, there's most likely a nuget restore error. Which version did you install ?

Comment: 1.1.0-dev.2 is installed.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it, namespace still not available. I'll try using the source code instead.

Comment: What project are you adding the package to ? It should be available for any .net standard project.

Comment: It's not open source at least not yet.

Comment: The namespace works on a new project (oddly it works without the nuget package?). On the project in question, this is what intellisense shows when trying to get the namespace: [screenshot1](https://i.ibb.co/FnCKrTS/Annotation-2020-09-02-161524.jpg) [screenshot2](https://i.ibb.co/ySzT0WV/Annotation-2020-09-02-16152114.jpg)

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is related to your project's name. Does it end with Uno ? If so, you'll need to prefix the type with `global::`

Comment: I just tried the source and it warned me that it targets an old Win10 SDK that I didn't have installed (16299). Installing it now and I'll see if the nuget package works afterwards.

Comment: Yes the solution name is 'TiltedUI.Uno' and the projects are all TiltedUI.Uno.Droid, etc.

Comment: Got it. Having a solution named this way causes issues for types that actually begin with Uno.

Comment: I had no idea that was a problem, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: We're going to be adding a message mentioning that such errors may happen when naming a project this way.